# Platform-independent way to get the user's home directory in C++

Tags: c++, idioms, platform-independent, pwd, getpwuid

Currently, when I want to get the user's home directory in C++, I do:

```
#include <pwd.h>

const char* get_home_directory() {
    struct passwd *pw = getpwuid(getuid());
    return (pw == nullptr ? nullptr : pw->pw_dir);
}
```

but this relies on `getpwuid`, which is a POSIX / BSD library function; and it's C rather than C++. Is there a platform-independent, hopefuly more C++'ish way to do the same?

**Note:** A commonly-used out-of-standard library, even non-Boost, could also work. It would have to support a wide range of platforms though.

Comment: There isn't one. Nothing in the C++ standard says anything about home directories.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: I was worried that might be the case. I thought maybe the filesystem library had something like this up its sleeve... also, see my edit.

Comment: Use `cmake` and there you have all the freedom. Passing paths as `defines` or generating dynamically headers - everything possible.

Comment: AFAIK boost filesystem doesn't support it either. But it's not hard to write portable code for _specific_ operating systems.

Comment: @ArmenAvetisyan: That's a fair suggestion I suppose. Although I wish I didn't have to do that.

Comment: There are some platforms, such as smaller embedded systems, that don't have file systems (or home directories).  Thus home directories are not in the standard.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: The C++ standard doesn't even say anything about *directories* (yet).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: That's what `nullopt` or `nullptr` are for...

Comment: @KerrekSB: C++17 will, though.